# Confused with the formula range in python doc

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am studying the python range function according to the formula of the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range), but it does not work for certain ranges, for positive steps if it works for me, but for negative steps no.

python doc says:

> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula:`r[i] = start + step*i`,but the constraints are:`i >= 0 and r[i] > stop`

so,I'm tryng to use the formula to calculate `range (4, -2, -2)`

```
range  (4, -2, -2), r[i] = start + step*i ,i >= 0 and r[i] > stop
i = 4, --> r[4]= 4 + (-2)*(4) = -4,  
           (4 >= 0) (True) and (-4)>(-2) False = False
```

So, if you note, doesn't work for the first step, because the condition is `False` this range should result = `4,2,0`

What I'm  doing bad?

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Ya, this is really unclear.

Comment: Apply the python doc formula to negative steps in range (4, -2, -2), if you see it does not apply when i = 4

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at finding the first step for `range (4, -2, -2)`

Range function's documentation: `range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers`

So you have `start = 4`, `stop=-2`, and `step=-2`.

In the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, *`i` is always counting from 0*.

So the first element, `r[0] = 4 + (-2) * 0 = 4`.

The constraints hold. `i >= 0` because `i` is 0, and `r[i] == 4`, which is greater than `stop` (`-2`).

Comment: Ohhh!! Thank you!, So, `r [ 0 ]` is the first element of range resulting, but not the `start` that is `4`, right?

Comment: @FerMedina Correct